# rustc cannot infer lifetime in trait implementations

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I have the following code:

```rs
use anyhow;

struct InnerValue;

enum Value {
    Int(i32),
    Other(InnerValue),
}

impl TryFrom<&Value> for &InnerValue {
    type Error = anyhow::Error;
    
    fn try_from(value: &Value) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match value {
            Value::Int(..) => anyhow::bail!("Ignore this case"),
            Value::Other(inner) => Ok(inner)
        }
    }
}
```

`rustc` tells me:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:16:36
   |
13 |     fn try_from(value: &Value) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
   |                        -          ------------------------- return type is Result<&'2 InnerValue, <&'2 InnerValue as TryFrom<&Value>>::Error>
   |                        |
   |                        let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
16 |             Value::Other(inner) => Ok(inner)
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^ associated function was supposed to return data with lifetime `'2` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`

error: could not compile `playground` (lib) due to previous error
```

Even though `try_from` should be able to infer lifetimes, `rustc` is unable to do so. The most straightforward way would be to add explicit lifetime signatures; however, in this case, this is a trait implementation ([`std::convert::TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html)), so I cannot change the function signature. Is there a way around this?

Comment: `impl<'a> TryFrom<&'a Value> for &'a InnerValue` and `fn try_from(value: &'a Value)`? I’m not totally familiar with what kind of inference is possible, but it seems like there shouldn’t be a rule for `impl TryFrom<&Value> for &InnerValue`, and then after that it’s too late?

Comment: Rust doesn't have lifetime inference at all for functions, only for closures, which this is not. [Elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) is similar but has very strict rules.

Comment: It's also not clear to me what you mean by "cannot change function signature", because that's [not needed at all to make this compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8f9ea7e7a34048dd5579efb4188a456d)

Comment: There is no reason `&InnerValue` and `value: &Value` should have the same lifetime in the first place. There is nothing to infer because `Self` has already been determined by the time `try_from`’s lifetimes need to be inferred.

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot change the function signature of `try_from()`, you *can*
specify an explicit lifetime when implementing `TryFrom`, like so:

```rust
impl<'a> TryFrom<&'a Value> for &'a InnerValue {
    type Error = anyhow::Error;
    
    fn try_from(value: &'a Value) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match value {
            Value::Int(..) => anyhow::bail!("Ignore this case"),
            Value::Other(inner) => Ok(inner)
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles as you would expect (see [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2f673dba5ed28a137b3d5e5dc37ce9f9)).

It is not expected for `rustc` to be able to elide the lifetimes of `&Value` and `&InnerValue` to the same lifetime; see the [Lifetime Elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html) section of the Rustonomicon, specifically the following line: "For `impl` headers, all types are input. So `impl Trait<&T> for Struct<&T>` has elided two lifetimes in input position, while `impl Struct<&T>` has elided one." Therefore, the two lifetimes must be explicitly provided if they are to be the same.